# iPhone SDK Annotation/Callout bubble on an image/button press

Tags: iphone, mkannotation

Is it possible to show the typical iPhone maps annotation/callout bubble (MKAnnotation), on something other than a map?

I'd like one to popup when I touch a UIButton in a UIView. (i.e. nothing to do with a map!)

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but that's with an undocumented class known as [UICalloutView](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UICalloutView).

For AppStore apps you need to create your own custom view.

Comment: ok thanks! I'll just stick with a transparent Label. your input helped "EU Limits" :P